# Jira Rest Api for getting newest ticket

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

how can i get json of newest ticket in jira Queue page for below link

> projects/assitance1/queues/custom/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific REST Endpoint available for that. But I believe you can query it via the JQL. If that's suits, you can use `rest/api/2/search?jql=`

Answer (score 0):

This query via the REST API search endpoint will provide you with the list of tickets ordered by the created date, newest tickets first:

```
https://your.jira.host/rest/api/2/search?jql=+order+by+created+desc
```